# Calling NSObject superclass method with [self performSelector:@selector]?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods

I have a Subclass of NSObject in which I want to call IMMEDIATELY (a sort of -(void)viewDidLoad) a method (in this case to load a MkMapView): what's the better way to do this? I think I cant use viewDidLoad, so can I use performSelector?

```
SubClass.h

@interface Mysubclass : NSObject <MKMapViewDelegate> {
}
```

SubClass.m (1st alternative)

```
-(id)init{
 self = [super init];
 if ( self != nil ) {
 // THE CODE TO INITIALIZE MKMAPVIEW
}
return self
}
```

OR
SubClass.m (2nd alternative)

```
-(id)init{
 [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
 return self;
}

-myMethod{
 // THE CODE TO INITIALIZE MKMAPVIEW
}
```

What's the better (or correct) alternative? Its possible to avoid -(id)init? Or everytime I add a subclass, to call a method I have to write it into -(id)init? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you simply call that method normally? `[self myMethod];`

Comment: Btw, it's not really a good practice to omit the return type of a function.

Comment: I think you should start right away with a good introduction book on programming.

Comment: Thank you DrummerB, I have already tried it, the issue is in my answer to Nate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use `-performSelector:` in this context.  If you want to add a method that initializes the `MKMapView` when your object is created, call the method from within the `if (self)` block:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupMapView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupMapView
{
    // THE CODE TO INITIALIZE MKMAPVIEW
}
```

It is a matter of personal preference/style whether to have a second method `-setupMapView` or to simply leave the code for setting up the `MKMapView` in the `if (self)` block of the `-init` method or to break the code off into a second method `-setupMapView` called from `-init`.

That being said, it sounds like other things may be off with your setup.  Your MKMapView should [most likely] be within a `UIViewController` subclass (which will probably have an associated `XIB`), so you will be have access to `-viewDidLoad`.  Note that your `UIViewController` subclass will serve as the delegate to your `MKMapView`.

#### Update 1

In your `UIViewController` subclass instance (I'll assume you called it `ViewController`, you should have an `IBOutlet` to an `MKMapView` object.  Do this in `ViewController.h` either by (1) adding an **instance variable**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;
}
@end
```

or by (2) adding a **property**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;
@end
```

Now open `ViewController.xib` in Interface Builder.  You should have an `MKMapView` inside the view.  If you don't already, add one from the Object Library.  Right click on `File's Owner`.  Locate the row with the item `myMap`.  Drag from the circle on the right end of the row to the `MKMapView` in the visible view.

Your `ViewController` class now has an outlet to the `MKMapView`.  You will be able to send messages to the `MKMapView` subview of your view controllers view after it has been loaded.

You should have a property or an instance variable for your `SubClass` instance so that it doesn't get destroyed as soon as `-viewDidLoad` returns.  Do this again by either adding an instance variable to `ViewController.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;
    SubClass *istance;
}
@end
```

or by adding a property

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) SubClass *istance;
@end
```

Now, in `ViewController.m`, you need to define `-viewDidLoad` so that `self.istance` is set as the delegate of `self.myMap`.  In the comments, I had suggested creating your own initializer `-initWithMapView:`.  If you plan on having `SubClass` do some extensive set-up of your `MKMapView`, that makes sense.  If you just want `SubClass` to be the delegate of the `MKMapView`, there's no need for such a method.

Let's consider both cases:

(1) using a method `-[SubClass initWithMapView:]`:

In `ViewController.m` you'll have (within the `@implementation` of `ViewController`)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.istance = [[SubClass alloc] initWithMapView:self.myMap];
}
```

In `SubClass.h` you'll have (within the `@interface` of `SubClass`)

```
- (id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView;
@property (nonatomic, weak, readwrite) MKMapView *mapView;
```

In `SubClass.m` you'll have (within the `@implementation` of `SubClass`)

```
- (id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.mapView = mapView;
        self.mapView.delegate = self;
        //more setup of mapView.
    }
    return self;
}
```

(2) using `-[SubClass init]`:

Instead, in `ViewController.m` you'll have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.istance = [[SubClass alloc] init];
    self.myMap.delegate = self.istance;
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer, Nate, and for your kindness, I know i'm a beginner but help and patience is always appreciated. I have already tried your trick, but the precise method I have to call into -(id) init is -(void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *) {}, so if I write [self mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:self] XCode give an issue: "Incompatible pointer types sending 'SubClass' to parameter of type 'MKMapView *" and method DOESNT initialize MKMapView when my object is created. What's the right expression? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you should add your own designated initializer `initWithMapView:` to your class `SubClass` and pass the `MKMapView` whose delegate you want your instance of `SubClass` to be.  Then, from `initWithMapView:` call `mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:` passing the `MKMapView` argument that was passed into `initWithMapView:`.

Comment: That being said, it sounds like you may be misunderstanding what the method `-mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:` is intended to do.  Generally, that method is called by an instance of `MKMapView` on the object which has been set to be the `MKMapView`'s `delegate`.  To do that, within the `if (self)` block of your `- (id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView` write `[mapView setDelegate:self];`.  Then, when the `MKMapView` does start loading the map, it will call the method `mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:` on your `SubClass` instance.

Comment: But I have to ADD another - (id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView in my SubClass or SUBSTITUTE -(id)init method ? Who calls -(id)initWithMapView? It "initializes a newly created bar button item with the specified map view", but I have no button!

Comment: You will declare in `SubClass.h` and define in `SubClass.m` a new method `-(id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView`.  This is your own method.  Incidentally, this is also the name of a method on `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`, but it doesn't matter that your class and that class both have a method of the same name.

Comment: As to your who calls the method `-[SubClass initWithMapView:]`, presumably it will be called by one of your `UIViewController` subclass instances in a method such as `-viewDidLoad`.  Probably in that view controller, you have an `IBOutlet` property which points to (because you set it up to in Interface Builder) an `MKMapView` in the view controller's `XIB`.  On `-viewDidLoad` your view controller's `MKMapView` property will no longer be `nil` and so you'll be able to initialize an instance of `SubClass` passing the non-`nil` `MKMapView` as the argument into `initWithMapView:`.

Comment: Into my ViewController I have a MKMapView *myMap and -(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender { Subclass *istance = [[Subclass alloc] init]; [myMap setDelegate:istance]; } In SubClass -(id)initWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView {} ask me to return a non-void value.. thank u for your time!

Comment: I edited my answer to be better tailored to your situation now that I know more about it.

Comment: THANKS! your edited answer is the simpler way to do that! I have adapted your code to mine (the problem was that I never created a property or an instance variable for the SubClass instance) and now I can call the initWithMapView method from VC... thanks again!